# search multiple string in a column.using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

in my mysql table.there is a column like this.

```
     column_name
     apple
     ball
     cat
     daddy
     mom
```

I have two strings (cat and ball for example)
So I need to get records that match cat and ball strings.
I can get one using

```
   SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name='cat'
```

but how to get two records that match my two strings(I mean `column_name='cat'  and column_name='ball'`)
please anyone help me

Comment: Just like how you're doing it. `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name = 'col_one' and column_name = 'col_two';

Comment: I think you need an "or", not "and" -- you want column_name to match *either* of the given labels.  It can't match *both*.

Comment: But if I use 'OR' it return only one record (cat).

Comment: @DilsUmesha That's not true. It will return all records that match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use 'OR'

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name='cat' OR column_name='ball'
```

For reference 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_where_or

Comment: Any time someone links to w3schools a pony dies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `IN` statement, which acts as an extended `OR`:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM `table_name` 
 WHERE `column_name` IN ('cat', 'ball');
```

Comment: Thanks you very much